# Приходят пустые письма на почту, использую FormData и phpMailer

Tags: javascript, html, phpmailer

Приходят пустые письма на почту, использую FormData и phpMailer

HTML

```html
<form action="mailer/smart.php" class="form__form">
                <label for="name">Ваше имя</label>
                <input name="name" required placeholder="Александр" type="text">
                <label for="phone">Номер телефона</label>
                <input name="phone" required placeholder="+7 (_ _ _) _ _ _ - _ _ - _ _">
                <label for="email">Электронная почта</label>
                <input data-email="email" name="email" required placeholder="example@mail.com" type="email">
                <label for="area">Коментарий</label>
                <textarea name="question" maxlength="150"></textarea>
                <button class="button button_form">отправить</button>
                <input id="checkbox-modal" type="checkbox" class="form__checkbox" name="data" value="yes" checked="checked">
                <label for="checkbox-modal">Согласен на обработку своих персональных данных.</label>
            </form>
```

JS

```js
let message = {
        loading: 'Загрузка...',
        success: 'Спасибо! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся!',
        failure: 'Что-то пошло не так...'
    };

    let form = document.querySelectorAll('form'),
        input = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
        textarea = document.querySelectorAll('textarea'),
        statusMessage = document.createElement('div');

        statusMessage.classList.add('status');

    form.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            item.appendChild(statusMessage);
    
            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('POST', 'mailer/smart.php');
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
    
            let formData = new FormData(item);
            request.send(formData);
    
            request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
                if (request.readyState < 4) {
                    statusMessage.innerHTML = message.loading;
                } else if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    statusMessage.innerHTML = message.success;
                } else {
                    statusMessage.innerHTML = message.failure;
                }
            });
    
            for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                input[i].value = '';
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++) {
                textarea[i].value = '';
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP

```
    <?php 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$area = $_POST['textarea'];
$checkbox = $_POST['data'];

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

// $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '***@gmail.com';                 // Наш логин
$mail->Password = '***';                           // Наш пароль от ящика
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
 
$mail->setFrom('***@gmail.com', 'ASO');   // От кого письмо 
$mail->addAddress('***@yandex.kz');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Данные';
$mail->Body    = '
        Пользователь оставил данные <br> 
    Имя: ' . $name . ' <br>
    Номер телефона: ' . $phone . '<br>
    E-mail: ' . $email . '<br>
    Коментарий: ' . $area . '<br>
    Согласие: ' . $checkbox . '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}

?>
```

Приходит вот что

Пользователь оставил данные
Имя:
Номер телефона:
E-mail:
Коментарий:
Согласие:

Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка?

Comment: в форму добавь method="POST"

Comment: Не помогло. У меня несколько форм на сайте. Я закомментировал эту строку (настойку заголовков): request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data'); стало работать, но понимаю, что это не правильно. Как сделать правельно?